# AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'make_labels' in featuretools in Python

Tags: python-3.x, featuretools

I am trying to follow the Featuretools tutorial named: Predicting a customer's next purchase using automated feature engineering

For more information on Featuretools look here: https://docs.featuretools.com/index.html

The data can be obtained here: https://www.instacart.com/datasets/grocery-shopping-2017

I am getting this exception when I try to run the command included in the tutorial (jupyter notebook):

```
import featuretools as ft
from dask import bag
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import pandas as pd

import utils

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import os
ft.__version__

label_times = utils.make_labels(es=es,
                                product_name = "Banana",
                                cutoff_time = pd.Timestamp('March 15, 2015'),
                                prediction_window = ft.Timedelta("4 weeks"),
                                training_window = ft.Timedelta("60 days"))

AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'make_labels'
```

The es object is an 'EntitySet' class object in featuretools.

I created es using the following commands:

```
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'orders',
                             dataframe = orders,
                             index = 'order_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'user_id' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'eval_set' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'order_number' : ft.variable_types.Numeric,

                                 'order_dow' : ft.variable_types.Numeric,

                                 'order_hour_of_day' : ft.variable_types.Numeric,

                                 'days_since_prior_order' : ft.variable_types.Numeric
                             })

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'products',
                             dataframe = products,
                             index = 'product_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'product_name' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'aisle_id' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'department_id' : ft.variable_types.Categorical
                             })

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'departments',
                             dataframe = departments,
                             index = 'department_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'department' : ft.variable_types.Categorical
                             })

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'aisles',
                             dataframe = aisles,
                             index = 'aisle_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'aisle' : ft.variable_types.Categorical
                             })
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the util.py file. Make sure you clone the repo on GitHub and run your code inside of the repo. You can clone it with the following command

```
git clone https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-next-purchase.git
```